# Is sqlite.swift threadsafe?

Tags: sqlite.swift

Is it possible to use sqlite.swift from multiple threads (read/write same table). I tried to determine it from from build setting - but did not found SERIALIZED, MULTITHREAD or THREADSAFE words.
Does it use original sqlite3 C library under the hood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for the [SQLITE_THREADSAFE option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#threadsafe) is "serialized".

However, accessing the same database connection from multiple threads is likely to blow up because there is only one transaction per connection. You should use one connection per thread anyway.

Comment: Anyone interested in a Swift Sqlite library that has robust and **well-defined** multithreading behavior may enjoy looking at [GRDB](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift).